# What are those types of problems and what are the best ways to solve them?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I keep seeing problems like: I have 100 baskets, X has apples, Y has pears, Z has bananas, and then some baskets have bananas, pears, and apples, some has apples and pears...

I keep seeing them. I'm not sure if it's just me or others have felt this too, but do these type of questions have a name of some sort? I tried *combination problems* but nothing popped up.

So in the end, what are those type of questions' names?

If there is/isn't one, what's the best way to find the lowest number of baskets that has apples, pears, and bananas? (I know I put x, y, z but what's the approach)

Those type of problems always confuse me.

I hope it's specific enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually I see these problems in the context of combinatorics, and while they don't have a specific name as far as I know, they tend to always involve use of the inclusion-exclusion principle on some level.

Comment: "Probability," "combinatorics," ...

Comment: This sounds like it might be a problem based on the [chinese remainder theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/), which might give you more easily google-able terminology. This alongside Eevee's [inclusion exclusion](https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/) suggestion is probably enough for you to look into ^_^